# NameError: global name 'parentid_id' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting the following Error Message.I can't understand why it happens and how to solve it.

```
Internal Server Error: /location/0/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, i
n get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\myproject\radio\views.py", line 33, in location_show
    arrs = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id in ListFirst)
```

Modles.py

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    english_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parentid = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True,null=True)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=40,blank=True)
    regions_level = models.PositiveIntegerField()   
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

class Radio(models.Model):
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    regions = models.ForeignKey(Regions,blank=True,null=True)
    custom_url = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,related_name='radio_stream')
    attributes = models.OneToOneField(Attributes,blank=True,null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type,related_name='radio_type')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment,related_name='radio_comment',blank=True,null=True)
    publish_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Views.py

```
def location_show(request, id):
    try:
        radio_single = Regions.objects.get(id = id)
        if radio_single.regions_level == 0:
            ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id=id) 
            ListFirst = [f.id for f in ars]
            arrs = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id in ListFirst) 
            ListSencond = [s.id for s in arrs]
            arrss = Regions.objects.filter(parentid in ListSecond) 
            ListThird = [t.id for t in arrss]
            listFirst.extend(ListSecond)
            ListFirst.extend(listThird)
            ListFirst.append(id)
            radios = Radio.objects.filter(regions in ListFirst)
            return render_to_response("radio_location_show.html",{"ars":ars,"radios":radios})
        elif radio_single.regions_level == 1:
            ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id=id)
            listFirst = [p.id for p in ars]
            arss = Regions.objects.filter(parentid in ListFirst)
            ListsSecond = [s.id for s in arss]
            ListFirst.extend(ListSecond)
            ListFirst.append(id)
            radios = Radio.objects.filter(regions in ListFirst) 
            return render_to_response("radio_location_show.html",{"ars":ars,"radios":radios})
        elif radio_single.regions_level == 2:
            ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id=id)
            ListFirst= [p.id for p in ars]
            ListFirst.append(id)
            radios = Radio.objects.filter(regions in ListFirst)     
            return render_to_response("radio_location_show.html",{"ars":ars,"radios":radios})
        else:
            ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id = id)
            ListFirst = [f.id for f in ars]
            radios = Radio.objects.filter(regions in ListFirst)
            return render_to_response("radio_location_show.html",{"ars":ars,"radios":radios})
        except Radio.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

would really appreciate a little help if anyone knows where i am going wrong and can explain.

Comment: You have a typo (actually 2) - `listFirst` should be `ListFirst`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Django syntax (it's used multiple times in your code):

```
arrs = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id in ListFirst)
```

You probably mean

```
arrs = Regions.objects.filter(parentid__id__in=ListFirst)
```

You also probably want to change the line:

```
ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid_id=id)
```

to have a double underscore:

```
ars = Regions.objects.filter(parentid__id=id)
```

Comment: Gah, I had this same answer ready to post when the OP deleted the downvoted question and opened a new one instead..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeesh. That's a bit rude of the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,Very sorry for that,I'm a new leaner of python. I'll pay attention to my mistake in future. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for you help,I modified my views.py ccording to your notice. but I get a new error message: local variable 'listFirst' referenced before assignment, about Line 38 "ListFirst.extend(listThird)"

Comment: @user2831966: The issue isn't being new to Python, it's being new to StackOverflow. There's no reason to delete a question and then repost it again (you could always edit it by clicking the edit link), and it can waste the time of answerers. But we were all new once and mistakes happen. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hello,David,Thanks for help,I've solved the problem.There are serveral  mistake in my files. Thank you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Very sorry for my mistake. Thank you